# Using Simulink Parameters in generated code

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink

I use m file which initialize parameters in MATLAB workspace.

It is example of file:

```
Pconstant=Simulink.Parameter;
Pconstant.Value=3;
Pconstant.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'exportedGlobal';

Pgain=Simulink.Parameter;
Pgain.Value=10;
Pgain.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'exportedGlobal';
```

These parameters are used as value in 'Gain' and 'Constant' blocks. I generate c source code for this model and received following structure in model_data.c file:

```
/* Block parameters (auto storage) */
P_ParameterTest_T ParameterTest_P = {
  10.0,                                /* Expression: Pgain
                                        * Referenced by: '<Root>/Gain'
                                        */
  3.0,                                 /* Expression: Pconstant
                                        * Referenced by: '<Root>/Constant'
                                        */
};
```

Model.h file contains following code:

```
/* Parameters (auto storage) */
struct P_ParameterTest_T_ {
  real_T Gain_Gain;                    /* Expression: Pgain
                                        * Referenced by: '<Root>/Gain'
                                        */
  real_T Constant_Value;               /* Expression: Pconstant
                                        * Referenced by: '<Root>/Constant'
                                        */
};
```

Model source code compiling into model.a lib file which is used in other programs.
I can change value of constant in external c code:

```
parameters = (BLOCK_PARAMETERS*)rtmGetDefaultParam(model);
parameters->Constant_Value = 1;
```

But this solution is not good for me. Because I do not know where are used these parameters and I do not know fields names of structure.

Can I write code which will be set value in all fields of structure where are used Pconstant parameter? Something like this:

```
Pconstant = 1; //instead of parameters->Constant_Value = 1;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have defined the storage class as `ExportedGlobal` but in the generated code, it appears as "auto storage", so something's not quite right there.

To achieve what you want, I think you need to turn "Inline parameters" on in the optimization pane (see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/gui/optimization-pane-signals-and-parameters.html)), and then click on the "Configure..." button to define which parameters you do not want inlined, i.e. `Pconstant` and `Pgain` (see the bit in the doc about [inlining parameters](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/inlining-parameters.html)). The structure construction you have in your code is normally used when "inline parameters" is turned off.

I'm guessing you have Simulink Coder, so you should also have a look in the Simulink Coder doc about how it generates code for parameters in different conditions. From memory, it's generally pretty thorough.

Comment: You are right. All works fine when I turn "Inline parameters". I can use `extern real_T Pconstant;` and set needed value into parameter. Thanks very much.